# Getting TypeError: hidden1 is not a function when storing function under let

Tags: javascript

My code works fine when I run it as a function but when I try to store it under let it says "TypeError: hidden1 is not a function" in the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

```
let counter = 0;

function hiddenCounter(){
  function addCounter()
  {
    counter++;
    return counter;
  }
  addCounter();
}

let hidden1 = hiddenCounter();
hidden1();
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted to return `addCounter` from `hiddenCounter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let hidden1 = hiddenCounter; // remove the parentheses
```

By removing the parentheses, you'll assign the actual function to the `hidden` variable. In other words, with the parentheses, `hidden1` is getting set to the output of executing `hiddenCounter` which is `undefined` because it returns nothing.